# render component with an update local data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component with props and data.
The component receive the new props, i see the props and i affect the new props on a data but... no render of my component

source :

```
 <template>
        <div> <label :dataField="(userSelected.email) ? userSelected.email :null" </label>
    </template>



export default {
        props: {
            user: {
                type: Object,
                required: true,
                default: null
            },
          data() {
            return {
              userSelected: this.$props.user,
            }
          },
         watch: {
            user(newProps){
                console.log(" DATA = ", JSON.stringify(newProps))
                console.log(" DATA = ", JSON.stringify(this.userSelected))
                if ( JSON.stringify(newProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.userSelected) ) {
                    console.log("different props ")
                    this.userSelected = null;
                    this.userSelected = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newProps));
                    // the component is update but he doesn't render the html
                }
             }
         },
    }
```

Comment: Close `div` in your template. Also, try `this.user` instead of `this.$props.user`, though it may be irrelevant.

Comment: same result = first le component is mounted ok but if my prop user is updated, the component is not mounted just updated

Comment: What is `user(newProps)` intended to be? It's not contained in methods or watch or anything.

Comment: sorry , user(newProps) is a watcher of my props .  I use this to compare my  new props

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? As far as I can tell, `userSelected` is expected to have the same data of `user` and, in that case, wouldn't you be better off making `userSelected` a `computed` property?

Comment: I want  if my props are changed ,  refresh my component (label) with new data updated.   Here : if my props are changed , the component label keep old data , but this.userSelected  are updated.  I don't understand why my dom isn't refresh if userSelected  is changed

Comment: There is no need to watch the property. If the parent data (the data passed down to the child) are changed the child component will automatically update and re-render the DOM with the new data. Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/wmgtqptb/).